# Count Specific Column Name

Tags: vb.net-2010

I just want to know why vb not execute the October month data? Here was my code.

```
For col As Integer = 4 To ldtData.Columns.Count - 1 
If ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "1" 
Then cnt1 = cnt1 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "2" 
Then cnt2 = cnt2 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "3" 
Then cnt3 = cnt3 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "4" 
Then cnt4 = cnt4 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "5" 
Then cnt5 = cnt5 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "6" 
Then cnt6 = cnt6 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "7" 
Then cnt7 = cnt7 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "8" 
Then cnt8 = cnt8 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "9" 
Then cnt9 = cnt9 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 2) = "10" 
Then cnt10 = cnt10 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 2) = "11" 
Then cnt11 = cnt11 + 1 
ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 2) = "12" 
Then cnt12 = cnt12 + 1 
End If 
Next
```

For month 1 until 9 will count for how many data based on individual month, but for month 10, 11, 12 . it will execute as `cnt1`. Why?

Comment: Did you check what `ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 2)` returns?

Comment: @JohnyL yes, it return 10, but how come it can still execute in `If ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "1"` 
If in my datacolumn, `10-296GP` then execute with command `ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 2) = "10"` should get 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding `-` in every expected output after substring method.

```
If ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "1-"
.
.
. 

ElseIf ldtData.Columns(col).ColumnName.Substring(0, 1) = "10-"
```